# Multiple images in UITableViewCell with action attached in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to show multiple image in each cell of TableView which is coming from server and I dont know the exact number of images in each table cell.
Also when user clicks on any of the images then it will zoom in another view controller.
My question is how to design such table with dynamic height and how to know which images is tapped for zooming.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have designed same table as you are currently working on.

For that i have taken UIScrollview in each tableview cell so images that are coming from server will display in scrollview.

And to display images inside the scrollview, i have taken UIButton so i can identify which image is pressed.

This is basic idea what i am doing.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Try a making a custom Tableview cell with buttons. you can put your images in the button and onclick you can get the sender tag and display the respective image in another view controller

There are many tutorials available on the internet on making a grid view in ios check them out.

Here is a link of one to get you started
Hope this helps.

http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/04/14/building-editable-gridview-for-iphone-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Here we go: you need a custom cell to hold the photos array.

You need a custom UIImageView to track the touch. For this you have 2 options: you add a button on top, or you use -touchesBegan  (see below).

Now, when you tap a picture, it will tell it's parent (the cell) which photo was pressed.
The cell will forward the information to the RootViewController (the class with the UITableView) also adding itself to the information.

Classes needed:

- RootViewController (not implemented here)
- Cell
- CustomImageView

> //Cell.h
>
> import UIKit/UIKit.h
>
> ```
> @class RootViewController;   
> @class CustomImageView;
>
> @interface Cell : UITableViewCell 
> {
> RootViewController *parent;
> IBOutlet UIView *baseView;  //I use this instead of content view; is more ..mutable
> NSMutableArray *photosArray;
> double cellHeight;    
> }   
>
> @property (nonatomic, assign) RootViewController *parent;   
> @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *baseView;    
> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *photosArray;    
> @property double cellHeight;
>
>
> (void) didClickPhoto: (CustomImageView*) image;    
>
> @end
> ```

```
//Cell.m

import "Cell.h"

@implementation Cell 

@synthesize baseView, photosArray, cellHeight, parent;

- (void) didClickPhoto: (CustomImageView*) image 
{
    unsigned indexOfSelectedPhoto = [photosArray indexOfObject:image];
    //this will allow you to reffere the pressed image;

    [parent didClickPhotoAtIndex: indexOfSelectedPhoto inCell: self];
    //you will inplement this function in RootViewController 
} 

@end
```

CustomImageView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Cell.h"

@interface CustomImageView : UIImageView {
    Cell *parent;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) Cell *parent;
@end
```

CustomImageView.m

```
#import "CustomImageView.h"


@implementation CustomImageView
@synthesize parent;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    [parent didClickPhoto:self];
}
@end
```

And that would be the longest answer I ever wrote!!